# Случайная перестановка списка на Python

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Есть функция, составляющая список профилей:

```
def all_players_profile():
    l = []
    x = main.numb_of_players()
    n = 0

    while n < x:
        n +=1
        l.append(player_profile())

return l
```

Нужно написать функцию, которая, используя результат вызова функции `all_players_profile()`, вернёт новый список, в котором профили будут упорядочены случайно.

Совершенно не понимаю, как это можно сделать.

Comment: Попробуйте уточнить у того, кто задание дал. Возможно, имеется в виду список со случайным порядком элементов...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов    как я понял- да. в №10 будет 4 профайла, а мне нужно сделать №11, который будет брать №10 список и рандомом его разбрасывать.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это вопрос: "сделайте за меня"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отсортировать массив в случайном порядке в Python:

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(l)
```

В этом случае будет перемешан сам список `l`

Можно и без использования `shuffle`:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda *args: random.random())
```

В этом случае будет создан новый список.

Comment: Только shuffle не возвращает новый список, а изменяет его на месте

Comment: @andreymal если не сложно, можете написать готовый код? как- то сложно это для меня, не пойму с чего начать, что делать и чем заканчивать :)

Comment: @Denis Вы себе честно признайтесь, Вы хотите быть программистом или нет? Если нет, то зачем Вам учиться на него? А если да, пишите!!! Коряво, гуан-кодисто, с граблями, но пишите! Понимание как надо придет потом!

Comment: @sys_dev Я бы с огромным удовольствием, да вот только не знаю как. почти целый день промучился, не получается. а это нужно на завтра.

Comment: @Denis Ситуации в стиле "надо вчера" бывает очень редко! В ВУЗ-е всегда все заранее и это позволяет планировать!

Comment: @andreymal: Да, конечно! Спасибо большое за замечание

Comment: @sys_dev только вот я никакого отношения к ВУЗу не имею. я создавал эту тему не для того чтобы получить уроки жизни, а найти помощь.

Comment: @Denis: Так я помог же!

Comment: @IgorChubin так а как брать данные из №10? Я же не могу написать просто: def random_players_profile():
             l = all_players_profile
             shuffle (l)
             return (l)

Comment: @Denis: Почему не можете? Это как раз правильно, только `all_players_profile()` (со скобками)

Comment: @IgorChubin видимо, мне свойственно все усложнять. всегда говорю "не все так просто" :) спасибо большое за помощь